# How to properly sum the elements of an array w/out getting large random outputs

Tags: c, arrays, pointers

I wrote two functions and call the functions in main.

Function 1 – I wrote a function that returns void and takes an int * (pointer to integer array) or int[], and int (for the size). The function needs to initialize all the elements of the array to non-zero values.

Function 2 – I wrote another function that returns int and takes an const int * (pointer to integer array) or int[], and int (for the size). The function should sum all the elements of the array and return the sum.

In main I defined an integer array of size 5. Called function 1 in main to initialize the values of the array. Called function 2 in main to get the sum and print the value of the sum to the console.

**My problem is the program runs but the print out for sum we are getting is a large (in the millions), random, number and is not the expected answer of 15. Anyone who can help us get the correct answer would be greatly appreciated**

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <windows.h>
#pragma warning(disable: 4996)

void func1(int* ptr, int size);
int func2(const int* ptr, int size);

int main()
{
    int grid[5];

    func1(grid, 5);
    func2(grid, 5);
}

void func1(int* ptr, int size)
{
    *ptr = 1, 2, 3, 4, 5;
}

int func2(const int* ptr, int size)
{
    int sum;

    sum = ptr[0] + ptr[1] + ptr[2] + ptr[3] + ptr[4]; // *(ptr + 0); putting an asterisk makes it so that it changes the entire "ptr" value and the "[0]" value

    printf("\n\nThe sum of the integers in the array is %d.\n\n", &sum);
}
```

Comment: You should set the value by looping through the size parameters.

Comment: What are you expecting here: `*ptr = 1, 2, 3, 4, 5;`?

Comment: I was trying to initialize an array with 5 different integer elements in it (1, 2, 3, 4, 5), that I would later use to create a sum of 15 in my second function.

Comment: like [this](http://ideone.com/StlpdW)

Comment: You have to initialize at the point of definition, e.g., `int grid[5] = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 };`. You could assign values to the array elements using a loop within `func1()`.

Comment: I suggest that you use `cout` statements to see what values the variables have. When they differ from what you expect, then you can figure out the reasons.

Comment: Also, you should definitely learn about for loops. These go with arrays like jam goes with toast.

Comment: @Code-Apprentice this question is tagged as pure C so cout is out of the question probably.

Comment: My bad...`printf()` then @dage5

Comment: `&sum` : Remove `&`.

Answer (score 4):

```
*ptr = 1, 2, 3, 4, 5;
```

does *not* do what you think it does. It actually evaluates all the integer constants but sets `ptr[0]` to be `1` (see comma operator for more detail), leaving all the others at some arbitrary value.

Note that it is *not* evaluating `*ptr = (1, 2, 3, 4, 5)` (which would set `*ptr` to `5`) but is actually evaluating `(*ptr = 1), 2, 3, 4, 5` - this works because something like `42` is actually a valid C statement, albeit not very useful.

If you're trying to set the array to increasing values, just use something like:

```
for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
    ptr[i] = i + 1;
```

You probably also want to do that when summing the values since it *should* depend on the passed-in size rather than just summing five values:

```
int sum = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
    sum += ptr[i];
```

Additionally, the value you are printing out is not the sum, it's the *address* of the variable containing the sum (a decent compiler will warn you about this). You should be using `sum` in your `printf` rather than `&sum`.

And, as a final note, the signature for `func2` indicates that you should actually be *returning* the sum rather than just printing it. So I would suggest removing the `printf` from that function and simply doing:

```
return sum;
```

Then you can put the `printf` into the caller (`main`) as follows:

```
int main(void)
{
    int grid[5];

    func1(grid, sizeof(grid) / sizeof(*grid));
    int sum = func2(grid, sizeof(grid) / sizeof(*grid));
    printf("The sum of the integers in the array is %d.\n\n", sum);
    return 0;
}
```

Note the use of `sizeof(grid) / sizeof(*grid)`, which is basically the number of array elements in `grid` - this will allow you to resize `grid` by simply changing it in *one* place to something like `int grid[42]` and still have all the code work with the updated size.

Not actually *necessary* for your code but it's best to get into good programming habits early (more descriptive names for your functions may also be a good idea).

Answer (score 2):

Line `*ptr = 1, 2, 3, 4, 5;` assigns `ptr[0]` value and leaves other spots unitilized so when you sum it, it will be random memory.

You should use `for` like this to initialize

```
   for(int i=0;i<size;i++)
   {
          ptr[i] = i+1;
   }
```

and similiar aproach to sum it.

Comment: It does not assign `ptr[0]` 5 times.